# Camel File Component: Write Headers / Properties

Tags: java, apache-camel

If there a way to configure the File component / endpoint producer to write the headers and / or properties? Desired behavior would be when calling `to(file:...)` it would write multiple files: someid.txt (body), someid.headers (headers), someid.properties (properties).

The corollary to this question, can you configure the File component consumer to read these files.

Comment: I guess you can write your own `Component` ? I've done so for testing purposes, and it wasn't so hard, mostly boilerplate code to get started.

Comment: True. I realize this. My question is if the capability exists so I don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible by default with the camel [file2 component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

The best you can do is, either:

- write your own `Component`
- write some routing in 3 parts which sets the body/headers/footers in the message body on the exchange, sets the required file name, and uses the file component as per normal operation.